# Skin modifier don´t show vertices

Tags: modifiers

When I have the skin modifier active on edit mode I cannot see my vertices. This is happening since I switched to 2.83. However, if I zoom far away I'm able to see the vertices. If anyone has a fix to this issue it would be very very helpful.[image: Skin modifier on edit mode][image: Same but far away]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices are obscured by the mesh itself. In order to see them you need to either switch to Wireframe mode or enable 'X-Ray' (icon to the right of the overlays drop-down).

[image: xray]

Comment: Thank you Rich... that was exactly what happened. Actually, my confusion was due to the fact that my mesh had a semitransparent material. that I thought it would be the same as the x-ray mode.